# Create diagonals in polygon with QGIS or ArcGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, polygon

How is it possible to create the diagonals in/of polygons and to calculate the length of this diagonals afterwards.

It's for a lot of polygons so maybe a fast/automatic method would be nice.

I prefer the software QGIS or ArcGIS.

The polygons are created by following streets that cross each other.
So the shape is very weird, not a typically square.
Some polygons has 4 vertices, some only 3 vertices.

The green lines on the second figure shows the objective, it's to create this lines and calculate the length of this lines...

I am asking this question because of the following situation:
I digitalise this polygon on raster data of year 1950. Then i search the same ways in the raster data of year 2014. I try to digitalize the same polygon as in the year 1950.

But unfortunate the area (inside the ways) aren't perfect the same. 
So i search something to compare the polygons of the same location of the two different years. 
I was thinking to compare the area or perimeter, but isn't perfect.
so my next idea was to create the diagonals of the polygons and calculate the length.
If the difference in the length between two diagonals (of same polygon but different years) is to large, the two polygons aren't the same and so not possible to use in the further analysis...
maybe there is an easier way to compare the polygons?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Would you be able to include some pictures to show us what you mean by the diagonal of a few different polygons, please?

Comment: Are the polygons squares?

Comment: no the shapes are very different, i add a little imag as an example

Comment: Do you mean a the diagonals of the *bounding box* of the polygons, or do you want the BND diagonals clipped against the figure.  Please take *one* of the shapes above, and using Paint (or whatever) draw what you are looking to obtain.

Comment: Your illustration seems to just show the vertices on half a dozen polygons so I am still none the wiser about what you mean by the diagonal of a polygon.

Comment: I add some green lines to show my objective..

Comment: It looks like you first want to define corners, and there will be three or four for each shape? But do you see how that's tricky? Your northernmost shape, for example, has a rounded top that at some point is not going to be seen as a corner... But if the polygon edges are from road lines, are the corners always where two roads cross? That might make it easier if your data has that info.

Comment: i know its complicated, that's why i asked it here :) So yea i think the best thing would be define the corners first and then create the lines between this corners... the data are old and recent orthofoto's (raster images)

Comment: I don't quite understand what's happening with that triangular one, the green lines look more like two sides than two diagonals. If you had a perfect triangle, where would you draw the "diagonals"? The simplest algorithm I can think of is to find the four pointiest corners and join them cross-ways, but that wouldn't be happy with your triangularly-shaped polygon.

Comment: It looks like you want to create the 2 longest internal straight lines (looking at the triangular one).

Comment: For a polygon with N points there's N*(N-3)/2 possible diagonals (lines between boundary vertices that aren't edges). Those could easily be all computed in Python in QGIS (or in R). What criteria do we use to select the ones you want? Length? Not crossing the polygon?

Comment: Maybe it's possible to use the four corners? i mean the four vertices where the coordinates are the most extreme in the four directions. Afterwars create lines between this four corners?
So first search the vertice that is located farthest int he north direction, the vertice that is located the farthest in the east direction, next one in south and laste one in the west direction

Comment: What happens for a C shaped polygon?  Taking a step back, why are these "diagonals" important to you?  Maybe you are looking for something that is easier and better accomplished using another method.

Comment: Please decide which of ArcGIS desktop and QGIS you wish to ask about in this question.  Otherwise you are effectively asking two questions which goes against the [Tour].